# Matlab Bsplines

Tags: matlab, math, bspline

I have to re-implement B-splines in MATLAB (interpolating natural B-spline, 3rd degree), but I have some issues making the B-spline natural (this means that `S"(a) = S"(b) = 0` where `S` is my interpolating function in `[a,b]`). That's what I did so far implementing [De Boor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor's_algorithm):

```
function [ b ] = deBoore( p,i,x,y )
% p is the degree, i is the index of the bspline
n = length(x);

    if p==0
        b = zeros(1,n);
        for j=1:n
            if y(i)<=x(j) && x(j)<y(i+1)
                b(j) = 1;
            end
        end
    else

       b = (((x-y(i))/(y(i+p)-y(i))).*deBoore(p-1,i,x,y)) ...
           + (((y(i+p+1)-x)/(y(i+p+1)-y(i+1))).*deBoore(p-1,i+1,x,y));
    end

end
```

So, this should work just fine, but I have to build the interpolating polynomial to look something like this:

```
function [ sp ] = splineB( p, x, y, f )

m = length(y);
n = length(f);

sp = 0;

    for i=(1):(m-p-1)
       sp = sp + f(i)*deBoore(p,i,x,y);
    end

end
```

It's almost working, but it's like the interpolation starts later than it is supposed to.  **What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?**

Comment: What do you mean by "the interpolation starts later than it is supposed to"?